# Can I create a Facebook ad that targets a particular user's friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-ads

I'm not sure I phrased it correctly, so I apologize beforehand.

*Ralph* has a Facebook personal account, under the email *Ralph@example.com*. *Ralph* created a fanpage (*Ralph's Toy Store*) using his personal account, so now *Ralph* has a  Facebook personal account and a fanpage for *Ralph's Toy Store*. Unfortunately, *Ralph* has no friends.

Ralph's girlfriend *Mary* (*Mary@example.com*) will be administering the fanpage *Ralph's Toy Store*. Mary has 500+ friends, and both Ralph and Mary know that her friends are a great base to sell the toys being advertised in *Ralph's Toy Store*.

So now Ralph wants to create a Facebook ad. Is it possible for Ralph to create an ad that targets Mary's 500+ friends?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it can be done by using email addresses, phone numbers, Facebook user IDs or app user IDs. It is call `Custom Audience`.

**Custom Audience:** Use email addresses, phone numbers, Facebook user IDs or app user IDs to create and save audiences you'd like to show your ads to. [Learn more about Custom Audiences](https://www.facebook.com/business/a/custom-audiences).

So *Ralph* can use *Mary's* friend's email ids, phone numbers or Facebook user ids to target them.

See the [targeting options](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/717368264947302).
See more details about [Audience Targeting Options](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/633474486707199).